# Finding Reachable Destinations From Source

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a very interesting question regarding how to find a list of reachable destinations given a source (starting point) that only takes at most n moves.

For example, I have a dictionary like:

```
source_destination = {
                      "A": ["B", "D"],
                      "B": ["C"],
                      "C": ["D", "A"],
                      "D": ["A"],
                     }
```

So in this example, in 1 move starting at "A", the reachable destinations are "B" and "C" because there is a move between "A" -> "B" and "A" -> "D".
If only 2 moves starting at "B", then reachable destinations would be "C", "D", "A" because in 2 moves the paths are "B" -> "C" -> "D" and "B" -> "C" -> "A" which both paths are at most 2 moves starting at "B". I don't include the source (starting point) in my reachable destinations.

I need an algorithm that is simple since I am a new beginner but the idea as given above. I am totally lost on this problem but here's my attempt:

```
def reach_dest(source, n, connections):

   while i < n:
    for dest in connections[source]:
        if dest in connections:
            source= dest
    n += 1
```

Where connections is a dictionary like source_destination dictionary and n is the most number of moves to take and source is the starting point.

Comment: Simple BFS would solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505431/breadth-first-search-and-depth-first-search/2508261

Comment: Is there a way to do it for a beginner programmer taking intro to programming? I haven't learnt BFS but this problem is based on that course

Comment: You have a convenient adjacency list and a breadth first search with a limitation on the number of levels as number of moves will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you provide pseudocode since I am totally lost on how to apply BFS for this problem since I am taking intro to programming and have never learnt this in my class

Comment: Ok I implemented bfs but how do I keep track of depth level from starting position? I can show you what I have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally BFS is written with a queue, and I think this is unnecessary and also somewhat confusing. I've written it the way one might think of it in pictures, with a fringe which expands step by step.

```
def bfs(n, neighbors, source):
    fringe = [source]
    seen = dict()

    for i in range(n):
        next_fringe = []
        for u in fringe:
            for v in neighbors[u]:
                if v not in seen.keys():
                    next_fringe.append(v)
                    seen[v] = i + 1
        fringe = next_fringe

    return seen


source_destination = {"A": ["B", "D"], "B": ["C"], "C": ["D", "A"], "D": ["A"]}
print(bfs(3, source_destination, "A"))
```

This also keeps track of distance. I would encourage you to think carefully about this code and why it is correct!

Comment: For the example bfs(2, source_destination, "A"), I was supposed to get ["A", "B", "C", "D"] but I ended up getting ["B", "C", "D"]. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You mentioned "I don't include the source (starting point) in my reachable destinations." Thus I added in `del seen[source]`. You can simply remove this line.

Comment: The reason for this output is because if starting from "A" and only require 2 moves at most, then the possible paths are: "A" -> "B" -> "C" and "A" -> "D" -> "A". Now in the second case, I include "A" because it is a reachable destination (returns to itself) based on the path. A little confusing

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, remove the del, and also replace the initialization of `seen` to just `set()`. Now, source will not be in there initially, but you can reach it at a later point in time.

Comment: I get an error when replacing seen initialization with set and removed del keyword. Would you mind editing your post to see what you mean?

Comment: I got an Attribute Error: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Whoops - because it should be a dict. I'll edit again.

Comment: Ok now everything works well. How do I guarantee that it works for all edge cases?

Comment: When thinking about objects like graphs, it helps to prove things mathematically. Consider any vertex v, which has distance d from your source, u. So there is a path of length d from from u to v, and there is no path of length d-1 or shorter from u to v. Inductively, the bfs will reach a neighbor of v in d-1 steps. Then on the next step of the bfs, v will be reached, and marked with distance d.

Comment: As far as considering the implementation itself (and not the algorithm), I would guess that something with as low complexity as a bfs is OK if it passes a few handwritten cases.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've learnt alot about BFS so I'll keep that in mind. I accepted your answer

Comment: One more question: will algorithm work for very large datasets?

Comment: BFS will work in linear time. You can handle large datasets of size 10^5 probably just fine. But, Python is slow, and if you want to go above that reliably, you will want to write code in a different language, or look into Python libraries which optimize code or provide efficient BFS implementation.